# Best practice two domains on one codebase and database

Tags: domain-access

I have one main domain name at site.com and I simply want to create blog.site.com using the same codebase and database. The only ways I see I can do that are by:

- Using another install
- Using a multi-site install
- Using Domain Access

Among those 3 options, the most straightforward way to keep using one single codebase and database seems to be Domain Access but I wonder if it's not overkill for my use case?

This is with Drupal 7.

Comment: This really depends on your use case. If you describe your requirements, you will get more accurate suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you need to do with the Blog vs. the regular site. For [Flocknote](http://www.flocknote.com/), we decided to use [www.flocknote.com/blog](http://www.flocknote.com/blog) for the blog (so it would be easy to maintain as part of the rest of the website), but also have [blog.flocknote.com](http://blog.flocknote.com/) redirect to the /blog URL (we set that up through a simple .htaccess rule, but you could also set up the redirect through your DNS provider).

If you really don't want the blog running within the same interface/site as the main site, but still want it running on Drupal, you can do that with one of the methods you mention. Just install another drupal site at `blog.example.com` using a database prefix (see [Sharing a single database across multiple sites](http://drupal.org/node/2622)). Domain Access is a great solution if you plan on setting up more than a few subdomains on the same codebase, but it's overkill if you *just* want to run a `blog.` subdomain.

Or, if you want to set up another database, you could create a folder `blog.example.com` in the sites folder, point the `blog` subdomain/virtualhost to the same directory as the main site, and then use the separate database when installing Drupal.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my concern. Definitely not worth it and I'll go with /blog and a visible DNS redirect from blog. to /blog - Thanks!

Comment: Guys, quick unrelated question: what is the advantage of having a visible DNS redirect from blog. to /blog? why not just use the /blog version only? thanks.

Comment: To Mario: many people, when trying to get to a blog directly, will type in blog.example.com. The redirect catches those people. It's not a huge number, but I figure if someone's looking for it, why not give it to them (with a redirect). Same for planet., mail., etc. subdomains.